# Cleaner way of filtering datetime by week in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, datetime

I have a large database of records with dates. When the user selects MTD the programs counts the number of records in each 7 day span starting today (not using the weeks of the current month so I can't use .Day or .GetWeekOfMonth). Right now it looks like this:

```
    if (options.timeRange == "MTD")
{
    if (x.close_dt.Value.Date < DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1))
    {
        complete = true;
    }
    if (DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1).Date <= x.close_dt.Value.Date && x.close_dt.Value.Date <= DateTime.Today)
    {
        if (DateTime.Today.AddDays(-6).Date <= x.close_dt.Value.Date && x.close_dt.Value.Date <= DateTime.Today.Date)
        {
            chartObj.weeks[0]++;
        }
        else if (DateTime.Today.AddDays(-13).Date <= x.close_dt.Value.Date && x.close_dt.Value.Date <= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7).Date)
        {
            chartObj.weeks[1]++;
        }
        else if (DateTime.Today.AddDays(-20).Date <= x.close_dt.Value.Date && x.close_dt.Value.Date <= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-14).Date)
        {
            chartObj.weeks[2]++;
        }
        else if (DateTime.Today.AddDays(-27).Date <= x.close_dt.Value.Date && x.close_dt.Value.Date <= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-21).Date)
        {
            chartObj.weeks[3]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your  help

Comment: What exactly is this function supposed to do? If its MTD why are you subtracting a month?

Comment: @maccettura This is inside a foreach loop. x is the current record and record are sorted by date descending. The function counts the number of records in each "week". Week being the previous 7 day spans. the x.close_dt.Value.Date < DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1) ends the loop if the record is older than a month.

Comment: I still don't think I understand your requirements.  If "week" is defined as the previous 7 days from today, then when do we stop counting "weeks"?  Lets say today is 7/11/17, the previous week is 7/4-7/11, but the previous week to that would dip into June.  Should that "week" be partial?  Should it dip into June to complete the "week"?  If so that changes the meaning of MTD (Month to Date).

Comment: Also, your code above seems to make the assumption that a month is 31 days.  What about months that are 30?  What about February?

Comment: I realize I wasn't using MTD correctly. I should say "Previous 4 weeks". And yes it would go into June. The last 28-31 if is a remnant from something else I was trying so I got rid of that.

Comment: OK so you just want to count the previous 4 weeks, even if it goes into different months?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure I follow you correctly, but if you just want to check for the previous 4 weeks of todays date and increment each "week" count you can simplify your code a lot.

First, keep your code DRY by not repeating common code:

```
private static bool DateInRange(DateTime date, DateTime minDate, DateTime maxDate)
{
    return date.Date > minDate.Date && date.Date <= maxDate.Date;
}
```

Then change your `foreach` loop to this:

```
//Store todays date in a variable so you don't grab it every time 
//(it changes every "tick" you know)
var todaysDate = DateTime.Now;

foreach(var date in sampleDates)
{
    //Date is out of our 4 "week" range, skip to next loop
    if(date.Date < todaysDate.AddDays(-28).Date || date.Date > todaysDate.Date)
    {
        continue;
    }

    //Using simple math we skip a lot of unnecessary code
    //This loop runs 4 times
    //-7 - 0
    //-14 - -7
    //-21 - -14
    //-28 - -21
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {            
        if(DateInRange(date, todaysDate.AddDays((i + 1) * -7), todaysDate.AddDays(-7 * i)))
        {
            //Increment our "week's" counter
            weekCount[i]++;
        }
    }                       
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9padB0)

Comment: @PatrickD. make sure you test & debug it a bit, I just threw it together quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily via `Enumerable.Range` and `ToDictionary`:

```
var recordsByWeek = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).ToDictionary(i => i + 1, i =>
{
    var start = DateTime.Today.AddDays(7 * i);
    var end = start.AddDays(7);
    return records.Where(r => start <= r.Date && r.Date < end).ToList();
});
```

Then, you can simply do something like:

```
Week 1 Record Count: @recordsByWeek[1].Count;
```

**UPDATE**

I initially missed the part about it being *previous* weeks. The code is mostly the same, but with slight modifications. I'm leaving the original for comparison and in case someone on the interwebs stumbles upon this and actually needs that instead.

```
var recordsByWeek = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Reverse().ToDictionary(i => 4 - i, i =>
{
    var end = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7 * i);
    var start = end.AddDays(-7);
    return records.Where(r => start <= r.Date && r.Date < end).ToList();
});
```

Essentially, you just reverse the enumerable so it's `3, 2, 1, 0` instead of `0, 1, 2, 3`. Then, to get the week number, your subtract `i` from `4`, which then gives you `1, 2, 3, 4`. Finally, the calculation for `start` and `end` is basically flipped, so that we determine `end` first, using the enumerable value and then figure out `start` by subtracting 7 days from that.

Oh, and one more thing, this is actually *exclusive* of today. If you need to include today as well, such that the 4th week would count records from today, then you just need to add an extra day in when calculating `end`:

```
var end = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7 * i + 1);
```